# How can I refuse to serve index.html if the request comes with an incorrect Origin?

Tags: reactjs, apache

I'm developing a Chatbot with a React frontend, an Apache server and a load balancer on top of it. I added CORS configuration on Apache like so on the appropriate VirtualHost:

```
  Require all granted
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "myURL"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST,GET,PUT"
  Header always set Access-Control-Max-Age "3600"
  Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Authorization"
  Header always set Access-Control-Expose-Headers "Authorization"
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} OPTIONS
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1 [R=200,L]
```

Whenever I make a request with a different Origin, I get the CORS headers, but it also returns 200 and the page contents. How can I make it so it returns a 401 and nothing on the body?

Is there anything I can do application-side? What about on Apache?

Comment: The answer is that you don’t want to be doing any server-side blocking based on the value of the Origin header — because the Origin header is spoofable. Origin values are essentially only useful to browsers, for browser-side blocking of responses (which is what CORS is about, not server-side blocking) — and that’s because, when a request is made from frontend JavaScript code running in the browser, the browser is the only tool which knows the origin the request was actually made from.

Comment: If you want to do server-side blocking in Apache, there are existing built-in `mod_auth*` authentication/access-control mechanisms you can use with Apache that have nothing at all to do with the Origin header. For the details, see the docs at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/auth.html. In particular, there’s a `mod_authz_host` mechanism that enables you to control access based on IP address or hostname. For details, see the docs at https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html

Comment: Thanks, but I really need it to be conditional on the Origin header, it's my client's requirement to pass their vulnerabilities test. Any ideas?

Comment: With `mod_authz_host` enabled, add a single line like this: `Require host example.org`, to control access based on the true hostname of the remote host. That will have the same effect as whatever you might try to write using the value of the Origin header — which for the purpose described in the question is functionally the same as the hostname. And it would not be trivially possible to bypass it — unlike anything you might write up using the value of the Origin header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm aware of the security risks, but if someone ever needs to do this, it's actually quite simple.

You can use mod_rewrite or If..Else statements and add it to a .htaccess file or httpd.conf. Here's the solution with If..Else:

```
<If "%{HTTP:Origin} in { 'yourURL' }">
    Require all granted
</If>
<ElseIf "%{HTTP:Origin} == ''">
  Require all granted
</ElseIf>
<Else>
    Require all denied
</Else>
```

I also allowed requests without Origin, but you can just remove the ElseIf otherwise.